# Javascript dropdown menu to move onto the next "stage"

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have seen multiple questions on how to make a "dropdown" menu, kind of like this (this is the look I am trying to get):
http://gyazo.com/1b024b83070785c9e4b6e0ee07f683c4

However, I am not really sure how to do this because I am extremely new and need to use javascript for something. I do not really know a lot but I have watch things to try and boost my knowledge before starting this.

But what I want to do with this dropdown menu is when someone presses on "option1" in the dropdown menu it will then navigate to the next "stage" and it will show new pictures and a new dropdown menu and different content etc. I am trying to get this into my website. Thanks

**EDIT**

What would be the basis of making images/content appear once a certain option has been chosen? - Thanks

Comment: What is it that I did wrong so I can improve on it in the future?

Comment: You are not showing any effort at solving the problem. *"when someone presses on "option1" in the dropdown menu it will then navigate to the next "stage" and it will show new pictures and a new dropdown menu and different content etc."* - this is your requirement. Do you expect someone to create everything for you..? where is the *next stage*..? where are the images, dropdown... HTML/CSS..? As it is, it looks like you want someone to code for you.

Comment: Oh right, that was not my intention. I was just asking if people had ideas on how to move to the next "stage" or to do what I have put in the updated section.

Comment: You can either have a hidden `<div>` with the images and all, which you can show on selection of corresponding option, or you can inject an html template from another file... just search how to show/hide an element, or how to inject dynamic templates there are lots of stuff out there... If you get stuck while trying to implement it, then ask a question regarding the particular issue, showing what you've so far... In short, narrow down your problem... or else you'll only get answers like the one below, which is already answered thousands of times...

Answer (score -1):

So you just want to make a select that does something when you change the option?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <select onchange="doStuff();" id="mySelect">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>
        <img src="" id="myImage"/>
        <script>
            var imageUrl1 = "http://i1.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/007/447/hello-yes-this-is-dog.png",
                imageUrl2 = "http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20071017205425/uncyclopedia/images/d/d5/Pedobear.png",
                mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect"),
                myImage = document.getElementById("myImage"),
                currentSelection,
                doStuff = function () {
                    currentSelection = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].value;
                    if (currentSelection == 1) {
                        myImage.src = imageUrl1;
                    } else if (currentSelection == 2) {
                        myImage.src = imageUrl2;
                    }
                };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: added changing image.

Comment: Oh right, well I have done that. Which is exactly what I am look for thanks. But what about when I select One, is it possible to make an image appear next to it when someone select a certain option? - Thanks